# jQuery stop all elements with the same class opening on click when element is a parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have written this function as a click event callback on a button, which when clicked toggles the class to provide a dropdown. This works if the dropdown element is next, but not if the element is outside of the clicked element's parent. The problem is is that I have multiple buttons on the same page that have the same functionality, and they all fire when one is clicked:

https://jsfiddle.net/21xj96up/7/

```js
$('.direction-button').on('click', function() {

  $(this).next('.direction-dropdown').toggleClass('active');

});
```

```css
.fade-in {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity .3s ease-in-out, all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contact-card">

  <div class="contact-directions">

    <a href="#" title="#" class="direction-button link-button animate-after">Directions</a>

  </div>
  <!-- end .contact-directions -->

  <div class="contact-info"></div>
  <!-- .contact-info -->
  <div class="contact-partner"></div>
  <!-- end .contact-info -->

</div>
<!-- end .contact-card -->

<div class="direction-dropdown fade-in">

  <p>Display #1</p>

</div>

<div class="contact-card">

  <div class="contact-directions">

    <a href="#" title="#" class="direction-button link-button animate-after">Directions</a>

  </div>
  <!-- end .contact-directions -->

  <div class="contact-info"></div>
  <!-- .contact-info -->
  <div class="contact-partner"></div>
  <!-- end .contact-info -->

</div>
<!-- end .contact-card -->

<div class="direction-dropdown fade-in">

  <p>Display #1</p>

</div>
```

Any and all help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I don't see anything in your fiddle working...

Comment: The first two are, but not the second two aren't, which is my problem :/

Comment: When I click the top two, nothing happens, should something happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if it has a "parent-container" named `contact-card` if so take next from that one else do what you did already:

https://jsfiddle.net/21xj96up/12/

```
$('.direction-button').on('click', function(){
    if( 1 === $(this).closest('.contact-card').next('.direction-dropdown').length) {
        $(this).closest('.contact-card').next('.direction-dropdown').toggleClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).next('.direction-dropdown').toggleClass('active');
    }
});
```

**Update with "shorter" version** https://jsfiddle.net/21xj96up/21/
Now this is even a bit better cause we use the same

```
$(this).closest('.contact-card').next('.direction-dropdown')
```

twice. So we can save it to a variable and then use the variable.

```
$('.direction-button').on('click', function(){
    var parentElement = $(this).closest('.contact-card').next('.direction-dropdown');
    if( 1 === parentElement.length) {
        parentElement.toggleClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).next('.direction-dropdown').toggleClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much @caramba, if you could give me some idea on a better solution it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Amazing, only I don't totally understand why you would use 1 === , or the .length, and why this is better than the previous one which was much shorter? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @lucasjohnson The way to tell if a selection matched anything is to test its length.

Comment: Thank you. As in if a selection has any length at all then it has matched something. Thats really cleaver.

Comment: @lucasjohnson as Barmar sayd (thanks Barmar). The first version worked and looked nice but wasn't complete cause I didn't test if the elements exist. Now this is no problem with jQuery but it is not clean to just call functions on elements which do not exist. Also I think it is important to note that the shortest amount of code is not always the best code. It should do the right things and be readable so if you have to change it in a few months or years you can look at it and you see straight away what it does...

Answer (score 0):

I wold suggest this code, since selection conditions are not the same :

```
$('.direction-button').on('click', function(){
  var b = $(this);
  if(b.parents('div').length>0) {
        b.parents('div').next('.direction-dropdown').toggleClass('active');
  } else {
  b.next('.direction-dropdown').toggleClass('active');
  }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In cases like those, when there is an inconsistent element-hierarchy, you can work with data-attributes and IDs, which makes toggler and content hierarchy-independent.

Attribute for the Toggler:

`data-toggle-target="display1"`

ID for the target

```
`id="display1"`
```

The jQuery-Code

`$( '#' + $(this).attr('data-toggle-target')).toggleClass('active');`

https://jsfiddle.net/s57zk5hb/

Answer (score 0):

On your code, since `$(this)` is inside the context of `$('.direction-button')`, this really means the "direction-button". There is no next "direction-dropdown" present for "direction-button" in the same level of "direction-button".

```
div
    div
        direction button
        <it looks for the item here>
    /div
/div
<item is actually here>
```

you can try,

```
$(this).parent().parent().next().toggleClass('active');
```

to achieve the functionality in the second case.

Answer (score 0):

It would obviously be better if the structure were consistent. Assuming that you have little control over that, though, would mean you also have little control over additional classes or ids that would provide a better solution. In light of this, you can find the index of the current button in a collection of all the buttons and dropdowns and find the next dropdown in that list.

```
var idx = $(this).index('.direction-button, .direction-dropdown');

$('.direction-button, .direction-dropdown')
    .slice(idx)
    .filter('.direction-dropdown')
    .first()
    .toggleClass('active');
```

Like so: https://jsfiddle.net/j7h32w90/1/

This will work in nearly any DOM structure.

Comment: Very clever, thank you. I am able to add ids or classes to the document, but I can re-structure the divs. Would this change your answer?

Comment: If you are able to add attributes, then @niorad's data-toggle-target is a good solution. Otherwise, you could give the buttons an id like toggle-[dropdown id], give the dropdown the corresponding id of [dropdown id] and find it in the click handler like `$('#' + $(this).prop('id').replace('toggle-', '')).toggleClass('active');`